# Paypal sandbox card payments not working configured cards

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have tried adding credit cards from the sandbox site Profile -> Credit/Debit Cards, and then used those cards that i added to test via the sandbox site. But none of those cards seem to work.

Further I've also tried the cards that are created via the developer.paypal.com. Even those cards aren't working and i get the same error as below each time.

However the payments does go through the default buyer paypal account created in the developer.paypal.com site. But the card configured for the same account seems to fail

Can someone point me where i might be going wrong ?

```
The card you entered cannot be used for this payment. Please enter a different debit or credit card number.
```

Further I've also ensured my "Payment Receiving Preferences" in profile page is enabled to receive all payments.

Thanks,

Comment: Sandbox account working?

Comment: Yes it is, My application redirects to sandbox. Further the dummy buyer paypal account from the developer.paypal.com also works and payment goes through.

Comment: Is your card successfully authenticated for details from bank?

Comment: not sure what you mean, If you're referring to the option in paypal sandbox site about "Confirm your card", then no I haven't done that. I'm not sure how to get the 4 digit code for a dummy card !

Comment: To make transactions go live you have to complete authentication process,maybe your card details or bank details.
If you have any issues regarding the transactions please refer : https://www.paypal.com/in/webapps/helpcenter/helphub/home/

Comment: complete authentication process even for a sandbox test card account ?

Comment: Nop if you are using live account you must get authenticated for bank credentials

Comment: cool, but at the moment i'm trying to get a dummy card to go through payment process in my sandbox account.